# How good is the idea to use behavior tree for player movement?

Tags: unity-game-engine, design-patterns, architecture, behavior, behavior-tree

I develop a game with Unity. Now I implement a player parkour (movement) system, so I try to choose pattern that will help me to keep architecture clean in the long term and easily add new states.
I tried to use **state machine pattern**, but I realized, that it grows more and more.

So I gave up on this solution and decided to use **behavior tree** pattern. But now I'm starting to notice, that this architecture is going deeper and deeper and conditions for parallel states become difficult to control. I think this is not a best way to create player parkour (movement) system.

*So my question is: is there a better way to create player movement system and how hard will it be to work with the behavior tree? Maybe there are pitfalls in behavior tree that I didn't notice? **I'm searching for architecture, that let me perform parallel states (or analog) by conditions and will be easily maintained.***

My prototype now looks like this (don't pay attention to get keys, it's just a quick plan for architecture):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A behavioural model encoded with Behaviour Tree is too strict and will get you in trouble quite easily. An FSM (Finite State Machine) is the simples and yet more complete and flexible architecture for any part of a game. A Behaviour Tree can adapt to simple brain functions typical of NPCs but definitely not to a human-driven player.

Comment: The problems, that I had with FSM are:

1. If I have two states, for example "move horizontal" and "jump", then if I want to move horizontally in the air, then I will need to create third state like "move horizontal in air". It's just an example, but due to I will have a lot of states in my game, these intermediate states will become a problem. (I read that Pushdown automaton to some extent solves my question, but I didn't go deep enough into it)

Comment: 2. For example, I use this FSM only for movement (like walk, run, jump, slide etc.), but lately I will need to create a FSM for combat system and I will need to create condition "If player is holding a heavy axe, he cannot jump". So I need to sychronize these two state machine. And with so many state it will be difficult, i think.


Or do you suggest any specific FSM implementation?

Comment: You have to build a state machine which in turn leverages the Mecanim state machine to manage animations, possibly with root motion translation for better realism: is not easy, it's a lot of work and thousands of lines of code. For the complex player controllers, I ended up using Opsive Ultimate Character Controller from the asset store, simply because the cost of maintaining over time a very complex controller doesn't scale for my small studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided that behavior tree will not be the best way for player. I will experiment with animator/animancer, so I will keep in touch with how my architecture is progressing.

Answer (score 0):

there is a very good article for you to understand deeply about Behavior tree.
Behavior tree is superior to FSM at all aspects. it is scalable and easily readable logically.
https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/ChrisSimpson/20140717/221339/Behavior_trees_for_AI_How_they_work.php